# UITableView's indexPathsForVisibleRows incorrect?

Tags: iphone, uitableview

When I check for a table's visible indexPaths with '`indexPathsForVisibleRows`' during `UIScrollViewDelegate's scrollViewDidScroll and scrollViewDidEndDragging`, it seems to be accurate.

But sometimes just when scrolling and dragging is ending and '`cellForRowAtIndexPath`' is invoked, the call to '`indexPathsForVisibleRows`' returns 0. There are rows visible on-screen so I know it can't be 0. As soon as this happens, I can invoke `UITableView::visibleCells` and get a non-zero value.

Why does this discrepancy exist?

Comment: I couldn't reproduce the behavior you're seeing. When exactly are you calling `-indexPathsForVisibleRows`?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Did you tried calling methods in below sequence:

```
[MyTable visibleCells];
[MyTable indexPathsForVisibleRows];
```

There is a bug in iOS with indexPathsForVisibleRows. Use above two line code to get correct visible rows.

Comment: awesome for [MyTable visibleCells]. Works for iOS 8 too.

Comment: I can't believe this bug is still in iOS 12.  Also seeing it the first time `scrollViewDidScroll()` is called when a table view is first loaded.

Comment: I always get count of 5 visible cells.

Comment: The bug is still there in iOS 13

Comment: The bug is still there in iOS 14.1

Comment: The bug is still there is iOS 15

Answer (score 0):

in swift, this works:

```
let viscells = tableView.visibleCells
let isThisCellVisible = (tableView.indexPathsForVisibleRows ?? []).contains(indexPath)
```

but this does *not*

```
_ = tableView.visibleCells
let isThisCellVisible = (tableView.indexPathsForVisibleRows ?? []).contains(indexPath)
```

### visibleCells and NSFetchedResultsController

be careful how you access `visibleCells`. the UI will freeze indefinitely if you `[attempt] to access the table view's visibleCells while they were in the process of being updated, which is not allowed.`

e.g. how you use `tableView.beginUpdates()`/`tableView.endUpdates()`, or `controllerWillChangeContent(_:)`/`controllerDidChangeContent(_:)`, etc

full debug message if this happens is:

> `[Assert] Attempted to access the table view's visibleCells while they were in the process of being updated, which is not allowed. Make a symbolic breakpoint at UITableViewAlertForVisibleCellsAccessDuringUpdate to catch this in the debugger and see what caused this to occur. Perhaps you are trying to ask the table view for the visible cells from inside a table view callback about a specific row?`